# How to force a splash screen to show for arbitrary duration

Tags: javascript

I have a loading splash screen as an element that I want to artificially show for five seconds. As it is right now, my page loads very quickly and you never see the splash screen.

How do I force the splash screen to show five seconds, and also make it show only on the first visit of a user?

```
<script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function(){
            var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
            document.body.removeChild(load_screen);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: take a look over http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, you should write your question in English.

Comment: I've edited your question and attempted to translate it. If you think I may have got the meaning wrong, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function with a delay with [`SetTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) for example:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    setTimeout(function() { 
        var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
        document.body.removeChild(load_screen);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Como eu faço agora para aparecer apenas na "index' uma vez? Eu já inseri o código nela, porém quando entro em uma página do site e volto para a index, o efeito recomeça. Eu quero que esse evento de carregamento aconteça apenas quando o usuário entrar na página index ao acessar o site no primeiro momento. Não quero que o efeito seja possível de ser refeito depois disso.

Comment: Store the fact they've visited in a cookie and check that as well then. Please write in English on StackOverflow. Machine translation only goes so far

Comment: Don't exist other way?

Comment: Cookies are pretty much the normal way of getting your desired behavior.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie is a good overview on using cookies in Javascript

Comment: I was in this website, but I didn't get how I to solv my problem.

Comment: Eu coloquei um gif agora na área do loading. Ele carrega normalmente na index... Mas quando entro em alguma página e depois tento retornar para a index, a animação do loading volta, mas o gif começa de onde parou e não do início. Como resolvo isso?